# How to resize child width

Tags: css

I have nice css task:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ghb3ahc/12/

```
    <div class="p1">
      <p>204204204200420424204204204420420420420420420000420</p>
      <div class="p2"></div>
    </div>

    .p1 {
      width:300px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid #000; 
      overflow-x: scroll;}
    .p2 {
      height: 30px;
      background: #902457; 
      display: block;
   }
```

I have parent div-element (with fixed width=300px and style property "overflow-x scroll") and two nested elements (p-element and div-element). P-element has innerHTML size greater than parents div-element width. At this moment nested div-element width is equal parents div-element width. Question is how (with css only) I can adjust nested div-element width: make it equal nested p-element width?

Comment: As you saying that you want the `p` and the `div` to always be the same width as each other?

Comment: Yes! same width as each other

Comment: Interesting, I'm pretty sure you can't do that with CSS. You'd need javascript.

Comment: I know how to solve it with JS, I know how to solve with html, but I was sured that there is css solve of this task

Comment: If there was a CSS way we wouldn't have HTML/JS methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the effect by using a wrapper element inside the scroll container and then applying `display: inline-block;` to that wrapper and the wide element.

http://jsfiddle.net/o3eejno1/

Comment: I know It, but task was not to use any wrapper elements, only css

Comment: Without a wrapper element it's not possible using pure CSS. Because you need a container that's growing in size when the children grow.